# Lambda defined within LABELS does not create a function? Does not execute?

Tags: lambda, common-lisp, sbcl, sicp

In working through SICP with Steel Bank Common Lisp, I have had reasonable success, however I have hit a snag on the "Picture Language" example.  The following does not seem to write to a PPM file, while the other rotations and flips I have written do.  I suspect that LAMBDA is somehow not returning a function when it called inside LABELS?

I have already M-x check-parens and nothing is orphaned or seemingly out of sorts there.

```
(defun below (painter1 painter2)
  "Divides frame along 2nd axis and invokes a painter on each region"
  (let ((split-point (make-vect 0.0 0.5)))
    (labels ((paint-up (fr)
               (transform-painter painter2
                                  (make-vect 0.0 0.0)
                                  (make-vect 1.0 0.0)
                                  split-point))
             (paint-down (fr)
               (transform-painter painter1
                                  split-point
                                  (make-vect 1.0 0.5)
                                  (make-vect 0.0 1.0))))
      #'(lambda (frame)
          (paint-up frame)
          (paint-down frame)))))

(defun krest-below ()
  "Tests BELOW on the KREST-SEGMENTS"
  (init-buffer 400 400)
  (funcall (below (segments->painter krest-segments)
                  (segments->painter krest-segments))
           (make-frame (cons 0 0)
                       (cons 399 0)
                       (cons 0 399)))
  (rgb-buffer->ppm "krest-below.ppm" *buffer*))
```

Comment: Functions tested and working: INIT-BUFFER, TRANSFORM-PAINTER, MAKE-VECT, MAKE-FRAME, SEGMENTS->PAINTER, RGB-BUFFER->PPM

Comment: Do you get any error messages?  Why don't you use `fr` in your `paint-` functions at all?

Comment: No errors.  I didn't use FR because TRANSFORM-PAINTER returns a function that will take it as an argument.

Comment: The answer was that I needed to make sure that the function returned by TRANSFORM-PAINTER was actually **called** with FUNCALL and passed FR when the labels PAINT-UP and PAINT-DOWN were invoked.
Thanks for the prompt, Svante!

I will post the answer when the cool-down time for self-answering has passed.

Answer (score 1):

From Svante's prompt I found the answer was that I needed to make sure that the function returned by TRANSFORM-PAINTER was actually **called** with FUNCALL and passed FR when the labels PAINT-UP and PAINT-DOWN were invoked.  The corrected BELOW function looks like this:

```
(defun below (painter1 painter2)
  "Divides frame along 2nd axis and invokes a painter on each region"
  (let ((split-point (make-vect 0.0 0.5)))
    (labels ((paint-up (fr)
         (funcall (transform-painter painter2
                         (make-vect 0.0 0.0)
                         (make-vect 1.0 0.0)
                         split-point) fr))
       (paint-down (fr)
         (funcall (transform-painter painter1
                         split-point
                         (make-vect 1.0 0.5)
                         (make-vect 0.0 1.0)) fr)))
    #'(lambda (frame)
    (paint-up frame)
    (paint-down frame)))))
```